# What is an appropriate sort algorithm for an embedded system?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, embedded

I'm developing the software for an embedded system, and I need to implement a sorting routine, and I'm having trouble choosing an optimal solution. My requirements are as follows:

1. Because this is a very memory-limited system, space complexity is a primary factor.
2. Because the number of elements to sort will generally be small, and the sorting will happen only occasionally, time complexity is not necessarily a primary factor.
3. A stable algorithm is a requirement for my application.
4. Because this is an embedded system, code size is a factor.
5. There is no guarantee that the data will initially be in a nearly-sorted order.

I've considered the following algorithms:

- bubble sort (yes, even though I'm ashamed to say it)
- gnome sort
- insertion sort
- in-place merge sort (though it seems to me that this is more ideal with linked lists than arrays?)

While the answer (for my exact circumstances) may very well be, "uh, duh, it doesn't really matter, use bubble sort for all we care", that answer is not very useful. **In general, what sort algorithms are useful on embedded systems?**

Comment: When you say small, how small do you mean? ~10, ~100, ~1,000 ~10,000? For great justice, test each of the classic O(n^2) in-place sorting algorithms on your system and see which one performs best.

Comment: Second question: do you really need to automatically sort things in your application? Unless you're displaying automatically the entire sorted list, you can probably do better than pre-processing with a sort.

Comment: Use insertion sort for small numbers of elements.  It is simple to code, stable and does the job.

Comment: Heap sort is nice, except that it isn't stable. I've used it for a 2000 entry phone book on a mid size embedded system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Insertion sort is fine too, it runs fast in practice, is stable and is in-place. It's very much related to gnome sort, faster in practice but for gnome sort the code is a bit smaller and it takes less auxiliary space (not in terms of big O, the difference is in the constant)

edit: yea I messed up a bit and got them reversed - I probably shouldn't answer questions before I've had my coffee.. it previously said that insertion sort has less code and space than gnome sort

Answer (score 6):

Don't be ashamed of bubble sort, it has its place. If your data set is of a small size, it's easy to code up and is stable if you do it right (don't ever swap equal elements).

It can also be blindingly fast if your data is mostly sorted, by alternating directions on each pass. I know you said it wasn't initially near-sorted, I'm talking about the possibility that it becomes so if you sort then persist. In either case, if the data set size is small, it doesn't really matter if it's totally unsorted.

This is *especially* the case if, as you mention in a comment on another answer, your data set size is around 11. Short of a sort algorithm explicitly *designed* to be intentionally horrendous, any algorithm will easily handle such a size fast enough.

If your environment doesn't offer a stable sort, I'd just go with the bubble sort, given your constraints and properties.

---

In fact, using the following program along with the `time` utility, I found that the CPU time used for `qsort` and bubble sort only start making a difference once the element count got up to 10,000.

And, even then, the bubble sort took less than half a second. Unless you're going to be doing many sorts per second, that will be irrelevant.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int data[10000];
#define SZDATA (sizeof (*data))
#define NMDATA (sizeof (data) / sizeof (*data))

int compfn (const void *a, const void *b) {
    if (*((int*)a) > *((int*)b))
        return 1;
    if (*((int*)a) < *((int*)b))
        return -1;
    return 0;
}

int main (void) {
    int i, tmp, swapped, count;

    for (i = 0; i < NMDATA; i++)
        data[i] = (i * 3) % 11;

    if (0) {
        qsort (data, NMDATA, SZDATA, compfn);
    } else {
        swapped = 1;
        count = NMDATA;
        while (swapped) {
            swapped = 0;
            for (i = 1; i < count; i++) {
                if (data[i] < data[i-1]) {
                    tmp = data[i];
                    data[i] = data[i-1];
                    data[i-1] = tmp;
                    swapped = 1;
                }
            }
            count --;
        }
    }

    //for (i = 0; i < NMDATA; i++)
        //printf ("%10d\n", data[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

By varying the size of the `data` array and the `if (0)` statement, I got the following results (in milliseconds), five runs for each case:

```
Data size | qsort | bubble
----------+-------+-------
      100 |    61 |     76
          |    76 |     76
          |    77 |     61
          |    61 |     60
          |    61 |     61  avg qsort = 67, bubble = 67

     1000 |    77 |     93
          |    61 |     45
          |    76 |     77
          |    77 |     76
          |    76 |     77  avg qsort = 73, bubble = 74
          |       |
    10000 |    92 |    414
          |    77 |    413
          |    61 |    413
          |    76 |    405
          |    61 |    421  avg qsort = 73, bubble = 413
```

I suspect the faster bubble sorts with a small data set are so because of the lack of function calls.

The thing to take away from this is that, for smaller data sets, the efficiency of the algorithm is often unimportant since things like big-O are usually relevant as the data sets become larger.

However, this test was done in *my* environment and yours may vary considerably. I would suggest performing the same measurements in your environment - implement a bubble sort and only consider moving to a more complex algorithm if and when it becomes necessary.

---

At the suggestion of a commenter, I re-ran the tests using `srand(42)` followed by `rand()` to populate the array elements. In that case, the results were only slightly worse for the bubble sort, 642 vs 413 milliseconds for 10,000 elements and 82 vs 74 milliseconds for 1,000.

Given the constraints in the question (small element count, infrequent sorting, stability requirement, low space complexity), I still prefer the simplicity of bubble sort to any of the more complex algorithms.

Still, remember my earlier advice: you need to time this in your *own* environment. The results may be vastly different. You can use the code I've provided as a baseline for doing that. Seriously, if whatever method you choose takes less than a second, it's probably more than adequate for your purposes.

Comment: why on earth have you picked `data[i] = (i * 7) % 571;` ? you should have mentioned that the data set is more or less already sorted :/ also, you haven't compared bubble with the alternatives I strongly suggest doing the tests for insertion sort.

Comment: Does this embedded processor even have an integer divider? 571 doesn't look like it can be easily optimized to an invariant multiply.

Comment: @yi_H, it's not mostly sorted, it's in 18 chunks, each of which is sorted (like 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,...) but the equation was selected so that bubble sort would actually have a _large_ number of swaps to do. You can suggest an insertion sort in your own answer if you wish - I don't think it's necessary since bubble is already blindingly fast.

Comment: @Mystical: As to the 571, that's not part of the sort algo, it's just to get "random" data, so it doesn't matter - use truly random data if you wish. I only used that so that I would have the same data for qsort and bubble.

Comment: with i=100 it's not a large number of swaps, you just have to move a couple of elements from the beginning of the list. with i=10000 it's also not true as you have a *lot* of equal elements. I'm saying that your measurement is very biased and quite useless. and regarding insertion sort: I already upvoted the insertion sort answer, that suggestion was meant to you so you suggest using the right alternative :/ BTW: you can initalize the random generator with a constant.

Comment: IC. Clearly I didn't read all the code you posted. :) I just saw the % 571, and it raised a red-flag. :P

Comment: @yi_H: that's a good point, I changed it to `(i * 3) % 11` so as to get more groups in the smaller (and larger) data sets. The results aren't that much different however.

Comment: But even with srand(42) and rand() for every element, bubble sort still averages 642ms for 10K, 82ms for 1K.

Comment: Don't know who downvoted but I apologise if I've offended anyone by providing solid data to back up my assertions. There's just no pleasing some people :-)

Comment: it wase me. it's complete rubbish, and I already explained why. also this is what I measured: I added a loop (20 times) around your code. the results (gcc -O2) 10000 elements: bubble: 3.14s, qsort: 0.026s. you haven't even compared the alternatives just stated that it doesn't matter because bubblesort is fast which is a lie. bad advice  can sometimes be worse than nothing.

Comment: note that this measurement is a complete rubbish too, there are only 11 different elements in the array, that's an ideal data set for QS, it eats it for breakfast.

Comment: I am saying that your measurement results and reasoning are not just misleading but completely rubbish. I'm also saying that if you want to use bubble sort use insertion sort instead.

Comment: I disagree: Bubble sort's only place is in the classroom, under the heading of "naive algorithms nobody should ever use".

Comment: Then you guys should write your own answer rather than clogging up the comment system. I will not respond again - interminable arguing is not what comments are meant for.

Comment: I, for one, am glad somebody is standing up for bubble sort. Bubble sort can be a great - even the best - algorithm in certain (albeit exotic) cases, and it's simplicity is more of a boon (in some cases) than it usually gets credit for. In any event, I don't see why the OP shouldn't benchmark its performance for comparison purposes... the results could be surprising.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that a system is embedded or not does not really matter.  What matters is the very factors you list:  code size constraints, available ram, speed needed, and number of elements.

With what you have outlined, a bubble sort is a perfectly acceptable solution:  it is small, predictable, easy on memory, and very easy to implement and debug.  I saw a proof in the early 1980s concluding that a bubble sort is time optimal for *n* ≤ 11.  It's possible that modern  quicksorts alter that slightly, but I doubt the break even could be reduced by much.

To make an unstable sort algorithm stable, add a sort key containing the original position.  Refer to the secondary key only if the primary is a tie.

Comment: That's right around the number of elements I'll likely be dealing with. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

remove the "on embedded systems" and change the question to "In general, what sort algorithms are useful".  Next, just try them!  What have you tried so far, what was the memory consumption, what was the execution time and what was the code size?

Embedded or desktop you should be performing those experiments and asking those questions.  There is no general answer because there are no general requirements.  Each solution has its place depending on the requirements.  One size fits all fits no one well.  The real question is what are your requirements, then you worry about implementation and meeting those requirements.  Is a sort even required, could this have been solved a different way?  Where does this sort fit into your overall performance number?  What are the other long poles in the tent?

Just like on a desktop, code them up and try them and see what you come up with.  There is never a reason to be embarrassed about mentioning a bubble sort.   If your requirements do not have performance or size numbers bubble sorts are good, everyone can read and understand the code, simple, maintainable, does not rely on libraries or versions of libraries, etc.  Not one bad thing can be said (if there is no performance requirement).

Answer (score 1):

[Sorting in Embedded Systems](http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2009/03/sorting-in-embedded-systems/), an article by Nigel Jones on Embedded Gurus is well worth a look.

He concludes that shell sort is his sorting algorithm of choice based on code size and performance.

Comment: Certainly pertinent, but shell sort isn't stable, so I can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Constraints on embedded systems vary with target platform and application requirements, it is often a trade-off between competing factors.  The factors you need to consider may include:

- Deterministic execution time
- Deterministic memory usage
- Minimisation of exectution time
- Minimisation of memory use
- Code size

For example you may have an algorithm that *on average* uses little memory, but that the amount of memory is not linear with the number of items in the sort.  You may then be better off using an algorithm that one average uses a little more memory, but the memory usage is more bounded or linear.  Similarly for execution speed, where a non deterministic algorithm depends on the initial order, while others are less dependent or invariant to initial order.

You may as seems likely in this case prioritise memory usage issues over execution speed.

So the answer is that there is no single answer, it depends on your specific requirements and constraints.  This [useful comparison table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms) should be used to help select the most appropriate algorithm in your case.

All that said, for the purposes of expediting a development, it is always worth just trying the standard qsort() function supplied with your compiler's standard library.  If that works for you an meets your constraints, no further work required.

Answer (score 0):

check sort.c in
https://github.com/LouayAlsakka/embeddedlib.git

it is O(N) no extra memory requirements beside the list to be sorted and very small footprint (few hundreds of bytes of code for 16 bit instructions)

It read the list N X (number of bits) X 2 so for uint32_t it read it 64XN times. it can also easily extended to int, and string sorting as well.

Comment: If you add an explanation, that would be useful!